# How do I force npm to reinstall a single package, even if the version number is the same?

Tags: npm

In my Node.js project, I have a dependency on another local project. Oftentimes, I need to make a small change to the dependency and see how it affects my main project. In order to do this, I have to reinstall my dependency using `npm`.

I can use `npm update` to try to update my dependency, but this seems like it will only work if the version number has changed on the dependency. I don't want to have to change the version number on my dependency every time I change a line of code or two to make an experimental change in development.

I can `rm -rf node_modules/; npm install` to ensure that I get the latest versions of all of my dependencies. Downloading all of my non-local dependencies takes several minutes, breaking up my train of thought.

Is there a way to force npm to reinstall a single dependency, even if that dependency's version number hasn't changed?

Comment: `npm uninstall some_module; npm install`?

Comment: Or `npm install some_module --force`? But I'm unsure of whether or not that command would have version-related implications.

Comment: @cartant Those worked for me. If you post them as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Noticed that you mentioned a local dependency; were you aware that NPM supports [linking local dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link)?

Comment: @cartant That's a good point, thanks!

Comment: `npm rb PACKAGENAME --update-binary` seems to do the trick

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you run `npm install`, it will install any missing dependencies, so you can combine it with an `uninstall` like this:

```
npm uninstall some_module; npm install
```

With npm 5, uninstalled modules are removed from the `package.json`, so you should use:

```
npm uninstall some_module; npm install some_module
```

Comment: This is not working, when I want to get the module from a git repository, because after the uninstall the git configuration for the module is not in the package.json anymore.

Answer (score 10):

On npm v 6.14:

```
npm install module_name --force --no-save
```

You get a message stating:

`npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.`

And then it proceeds to uninstall and reinstall the package.

> **Note:** if you don't specify the `--no-save` option, npm updates the package version on `package.json` to the highest version that is compatible with the existing SemVer rule.
>   If you do not want npm to update the package's version on `package.json`, keep the `--no-save` option.

Comment: This wasn't working for me in npm 6.14.5. Could perhaps be related to this issue: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1400

Comment: Thank you! I have tried a lot of combinations of commands but only this command working as I wanted and pull freshest version of my module from git.

Answer (score 5):

Not the best answer, but just for information, you can run

```sh
npm ci
```

It is the same as `npm install`, but it will remove the existing `node_modules` folder, if any, and do a fresh install for all packages. This is useful if the files in `node_modules` have been changed for some reason and you want to revert them to their original state.